# How to deploy ApplicationLifecycleListener

Tags: deployment, weblogic, jdeveloper

I created an ApplicationListener extends ApplicationLifecycleListener in a java project, packaged as a jar file, create ear file contains this jar file, try to deploy it in the weblogic server with the "install" button in weblogic admin console(screenshot), I got error. If I pack it as a war file, create a ear file contains this war file, with the same approach I can deploy it with no error, but it does not being called.

I have searched on the internet for a while, a lot of people was talking about adding this listener to a weblogic-application.xml, I do not have this file in my project, I tried to find this in the weblogic server folders also can not locate it, I am new to weblogic, no idea how should I make a ApplicationLifecycleListener work.

Where should I find this weblogic-application.xml file? Or where do I need to create this file? Do I have to create a J2EE or EJB project? Or a java project can do this.

If possible please give me some detailed steps about deploying an ApplicationLifecycleListener. (I am using Jdeveloper)
First what project I should be using to write this listener class, and after coding, how to I register it, what is the best way and how should I deploy it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a typical maven EAR project, you'd put it in `/myapp-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/`, and it would look a bit like this:

```
<weblogic-application>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.myapp.SomethingSomethingServiceListener</listener-class>
        <listener-uri>myapp-lib.jar</listener-uri>
    </listener>
    <!-- add whatever other things you'd normally put into weblogic-application-->
</weblogic-application>
```

Then `/myapp-lib/src/main/java` would have your listener code.

I like to put this code inside `/myapp-ear/pom.xml` but that's up to you:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myapp-lib</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                        </jarModule>
                    </modules>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries><!-- weblogic really wants to know this for hot deploys -->
                            <Weblogic-Application-Version>${project.version}</Weblogic-Application-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. From what you said, so the weblogic-application.xml file should be inside the project I created the listener. I am using an java project inside jdeveloper, I assume that if I create this xml file at the right location inside this project it should work, I will try these out.

Comment: I tried to do the same in JDeveloper, but it seems that EAR does not need to be an project in there and there is no place for me to create that xml file. I installed maven and created a project which has my listener, and required jar files. And created another project use it to generate EAR file, I created the weblogic-application.xml in the path you told me to `/myapp-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/`, and import my first project's jar file as a dependency. Then build this EAR project with mvn clean package, got an EAR file, but when trying to install this, it gives me errors. Can u help?